# mysql query to fetch data in comma separated form

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table (user table ) in which data is stored as below

```
| name  |  address  |
|  A    |  x        |
|  A    |  y        |
|  C    |  z        |
```

and i want output like below

```
    | name  |  address  |
    |  A    |  x ,y     |
    |  C    |  z        |
```

I need to show these values in a user table(html view) in comma separated value(eg. address1,address2)
Please help me to code it in php
I am using php in backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `group_concat` as

```
select
name,
group_concat(address) as address
from user
group by name
```